# Is it safe to download the "Java free" version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

On my old launcher, there is a message in red text saying:

> *You are running on an old version of Java. Please consider using the new Minecraft installer which doesn't require Java, as it may make your game faster*

I updated Java to the newest version (just to see if the message would go away). After updating java I opened up my launcher and it still said I'm using an older version of Java. When I try to install an updated java now it says tells me I already have the newest version. So I gave in and downloaded the new installer.

I tried using the new launcher after some debate to play on a minecraft server and not getting the message to go away. When I entered the server on the (Java free) launcher, the window kept freezing (Not responding) And when I tried to type for other players to know I wasn't able to move the text bar kept highlighting and deleting random letters and words from what I was typing.

I would type something like:

> *"I can't type, and I can't move my window isn't responding"*

and it would highlight random letters in blue and words in green then send as

> *"an' pe iwin'spo"*

The whole text thing was very quick and I cannot screen cap it. If I type slow the text gets deleted almost instantly. Like minecraft is the worlds worst auto-correct and I couldn't turn it off. It also took up more of my cpu than using the old launcher. But with less quality, it was definitely worse.

I immediately went back to the old launcher but I'm wondering if the new launcher isn't working yet (Still has lots of bugs) or if it is dangerous in some way since I haven't seen much evidence or updates from minecraft on my launcher page other than the red text.

Oh, also with the new launcher, when I open it up my computer wallpaper flickers, then all my icons temporarily become blank white page icons. They all return to normal pretty quickly but the 1 second everything seems to blank out is making me very afraid that this was a dangerous launcher for my computer. I won't open it again because I don't like my computer acting like it's going to blue screen.

I have Windows 7, 64 bit, on a Toshiba laptop with 4gb of ram.

Comment: Maybe you want to add which link and where you've downloaded what program (don't post full URLs just to be sure). The game itself should still run based on Java, just the installer doesn't (so it's able to download and install Java just in case).

Comment: https:*//launcher.mojang.com/*download/*MinecraftInstaller.msi << Is the link. I added some "*" so that the link is not clickable. It's readily available on the launcher. In the red font some of it is clickable and blue and leads to the link I added above.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce any of the problems you were having on my computer. This new launcher [has been in testing for about a month](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2p31cu/we_need_your_help_testing_a_new_launcher/), and the new installer has been in development [for about the same](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2pkxpx/we_need_your_help_testing_the_new_minecraft/). The only difference technically is that Minecraft will run with 64 bit Java 8.

Comment: Java free Minecraft, sounds too good to be true.

Comment: Have you updated both 32 bit java and 64 bit java? Possibly, MC prefers an old 64 bit to newer 32 bit versions. You can check what java Minecraft is using by checking the launcher log (tab at the top of the launcher). There will be several lines containing `system.getProperty` or something like that. The last of these is 32 or 64 bit, one of the others has the version.

Comment: Minecraft simply cannot run without Java. The code is written in Java, and the .msi would just install Java anyways. The "1 second everything seems to blank out" is normal. That happens during all installs when the installer refreshes the Registry with new values (like minecraft=installed).

Comment: For what it's worth, once I switched to the .msi installer of Minecraft, I started getting fatal `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)` error codes that crashed my game. Could be the new version of Java, but I never got the error before I used the MSI installer.

Answer (score 3):

The launcher has 2 flavors. A java based installer and a non-java based installer.

Both version install the launcher. Once that is done the launcher and the game do require Java. Given your post I would recommend that you download Java 8 for x86-64 if you do not already have it.

When you download the launcher installer be certain to ONLY download it from minecraft.net after logging into your account. If you download it from any other site or attempt to use a 'cracked' version then I wouldn't expect it to work and may Notch have mercy on your soul.

As with the game, be certain that you download Java Runtime ONLY from the trusted site.

If you have errors with Java 8 x86-64 then I would begrudgingly suggest uninstalling and installing Java 7 x86-64 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just downloaded your version and it is still Java-based. It just doesn't require java to download and install it. The problems you are having are not happening on my end. I would try re-installing the program and seeing if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Java-free version, but Java-free version is buggy and it comes Java preinstalled. That means, it doesn't use Java's latest version.

---

Also you said

> You are running on an old version of Java. Please consider using the new Minecraft installer which doesn't require Java, as it may make your game faster

I suggest you the [newer Java launcher](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar), as it works better.